# Is there any router / device that does the domain forwarding?

Tags: domain, router, forwarding

Is there any router or device that does the domain name forwarding? Currently we have only one IP address, and we have multiple domain names that point to this IP address. We would like to forward the requests to different servers based on the domain name. For example:

A.com --> 192.168.1.100

B.com --> 192.168.1.101

C.com --> 192.168.1.102

I know that I can use Apache HTTP Load Balancer module to do something similar. However, we prefer a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

You'd need a router that can do L7 packet inspection, and those are typically neither quick nor easy (nor cheap) to configure. I'd recommend looking into apache's `mod_proxy` module. It's *very* simple to get set up, and when used in combination with `NameVirtualHost`, it'll do exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need a proxy.  Examples include Apache with `mod_proxy`, nginx with `mod_proxy_http`, and haproxy.  All are "quick" and "easy", for appropriate values thereof.

If you're looking for an appliance, I don't know of any I can recommend, because the abovementioned options have been quick and easy enough for my needs, and don't have the arbitrary and impossible-to-fix limitations that the appliances I've used have had.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers recommending a software proxy will be cheaper and typically easier to manage.  That said, to answer your specific question, I am personally familiar with these two pieces of hardware.

- [Astaro Security Gateway 110](http://www.astaro.com/en-us/products/hardware-appliances/astaro-security-gateway-110)
- [Cisco Content Switch](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/contnetw/ps792/index.html)

Another option, if you want the simplest of all solutions, is to just pay your ISP for additional IP addresses.  They are pretty cheap in comparison to dedicated/additional hardware.